# Is there anyway to specify templates and static folders(other than default) for Connexion app?

Tags: python, flask, connexion

I'm initializing app using connexion 2.4.0 library like this:

```
connex_app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./')
app = connex_app.app
```

I need to specify the path to my static and templates directories somehow since they are not located in the root directory. 
In Flask I would use something like this

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../frontEnd/static', template_folder='../frontEnd/templates')
```

I know that connexion looks for static and templates in the root by default, but is there any way to indicate another path?

Answer (score 1):

Gids is technically correct, you can now pass flask keyword arguments to the created app.

The correct combination for your two code snippets would be:

```
    connex_app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./', server_args={'static_folder'='../frontEnd/static', 'template_folder'='../frontEnd/templates'})
    app = connex_app.app
```

Answer (score 0):

Has an opening issue about this problem:

- https://github.com/zalando/connexion/issues/441

And a opening pull request:

- https://github.com/zalando/connexion/pull/710

But the problem is not solved.
You can you this approach [How to set static_url_path in Flask application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722279/how-to-set-static-url-path-in-flask-application) just remember to use **app.app** to access the flask instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible following the merge of https://github.com/spec-first/connexion/pull/1173

You can now specify these arguments in the `server_args` constructor argument e.g.

```
connexion.FlaskApp(
    server_args={'static_url_path': '/your/path/'}
)
```