# correct javasript code execution in flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I tried to use click on button:

```
@app.route("/")
def test_edition_open():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

my index.html file is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
```

The main part is just two buttons:

```
<div class = "counter">
    <button class = "minus">-</button>
    <div class = "result">1</div>
    <button class = "plus">+</button>
</div>
```

I tried to make My script.js file work in flask. The code is very simple, it should add numbers by clicking on button:

```
const plus = document.querySelectorAll('.plus');
const minus = document.querySelectorAll('.minus');
const result = document.querySelectorAll('.result');

function min()
{
    return function (ev)
    {
        if (ev.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML > 0)
        {
            return --ev.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
        }
    }
}

function pl()
{
    return function (ev)
    {
        return ++ev.target.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;

    }
}

minus.forEach(function (dominus)
{
    dominus.addEventListener('click', min());

})

plus.forEach(function (doplus)
{
    doplus.addEventListener('click', pl());
})
```

In https://playcode.io this code worked well. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that script file successfully connected to html file. to check this add `console.log("File Connected")` in your **script.js** file. Then open your browser console to check that console message is logged correctly. If not then try to linked your static file correctly. [How to set static_url_path in Flask application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722279/how-to-set-static-url-path-in-flask-application)

Or you can put your Javascript code in html file using script tag.
Something like this:

```
<script> your javascript code here</script>
```